# Making line from set of GPS points using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gps, polyline-creation, python-2.6, trajectory

I need to create the trajectory of respondents according to the their collected GPS data (including X and Y).

I am familiar with python programming, but I am a beginner in ArcGIS.

I want to write a script to automate this process.

Comment: What format are your points in?  Shapefile, X/Y Table, GPX File, RAW NMEA?

Answer (score 2):

The [Points To Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003s000000) tool in the Data Management toolbox may meet your requirements so perhaps look at that before Python.

Comment: here is relevant help: http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//001200000050000000

Comment: @ndthl Comments are easily lost or overlooked. I think you should add and expand upon that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Sketch ("pencil") tool to draw, but instead of 1st point right click and select "Absolute x,y " or press F6 to enter your GPS points in window provided.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange!  Although the question was not very specific I think you are answering a slightly different question.  This question is asking for an automated rather than manual method.